# Adplus stop debugging process

Tags: debugging, adplus

I have a stupid question - how can I stop debugging?

I run adplus -crash -0 path -pid number -mss symbols ..

Then I got message that it was attached to the process. I saw logs and mini dumbs in the folder, but I want to stop it. What should I do? I do not see any commands in adplus help to detach it from the process. How can I do it? Can I just close cdb.exe command window or not?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can break into the debugger (in the cdb window, hit Ctrl+C) and then detach using the `qd` command.

You might want to consider using [Procdump](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/dd996900.aspx) to capture crash dumps -- it is much more flexible, easy to use, and supports both x86 and x64 processes in a single package.